# Flutter intl package formats minutes incorrectly

Tags: flutter, date, format, intl

The following code returns a date that is off by several minutes (note that I am running in US Central DST):

```
      final givenDate = DateTime.parse('1980-01-03T11:05:16Z');
      const expectedDateString = '01/03/1980 11:05:16';

      print("givenDate is ${givenDate.toString()}");
      print(
          "DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss').format(givenDate) is ${DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss').format(givenDate)}");
```

The prints show:

givenDate is 1980-01-03 11:05:16.000Z

DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss').format(givenDate) is 01/03/1980 11:01:16

Four minutes off. The formatted date/time should be 01/03/1980 11:05:16

Changing the constants:

```
      final givenDate = DateTime.parse('1980-01-03T11:45:16.735Z');
      const expectedDateString = '01/03/1980 11:45:16';
```

Results in:

givenDate is 1980-01-03 11:45:16.735Z

DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss').format(givenDate) is 01/03/1980 11:01:16

The minutes portion is still '01'. It should be 45.

I am running:

Flutter version 3.10.0 on channel stable

Dart version 3.0.0

intl: ^0.18.1 (same issue with 0.18.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format is incorrect. `MM` means month and `mm` means minute. (You are printing the month not the minute in the time.)

Change `DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss')` to `DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')`

Comment: nothing like missing the obvious. this is why one needs a pair programmer. thanks!